# Django. Mezzanine new project not importing all files

Tags: django, settings, mezzanine

I wanted to start playing around with Django again (I'm not an expert in Python/Django, but I can make nice things work tho). I used Mezzanine once just to see how it worked. The 'mezzanine-project myproject' command worked like a charm as I had a nice small app running quickly. So, today I downloaded the new Mezzanine 1.3 along with Django 1.4.3 and all its dependencies (pillow, pytz, html5lib, etc) and tried to create another project so I could now work on it in a more consistent manner for personal purposes.

For my surprise, when I ran the server, I got lots of 404 errors pointing to missing /static/ files. Also, after creating the database (with `manage.py createdb` command), the only thing created was the static folder containing only the pictures of the predefined gallery that come along with Mezzanine. Also, there is no Log in or signup buttons as well.

I've tried making a clean install of all Python and its site-packages with the same result. I also tried copying/pasting the folders containing missing files from the /site-packages/mezzanine folder into my project, but the result was just reducing the number of 404 messages.

I've been doing an extensive research on this issue (with no luck but maybe because of the release being recent?) and even trying to contact someone on the Mezzanine IRC channel with no success.

I hope I'm not missing something silly. Do I have to change anything (note that I'm ok with the old mezzanine default settings) in my `settings.py` or in a specific file before running `manage.py createdb` command?

For the record: before running `createdb`, The only thing I edited was `settings.py` and changed the database parameters to make it work with my MySQL Server and commenting the local_settings configuration as I do not need it.

Some parameters that could be of help:

`PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`

`STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, STATIC_URL.strip("/"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, DEBUG is set to False in settings.py, and DEBUG is set to True in local_setting.py

Given that, if you just commented out importing local_settings.py, DEBUG would be False.

Django's development server won't serve static files when DEBUG is set to False, see the staticfiles section of the Django docs for more details.